# Automator Service Shelll script :Sorting selected text wrt second parameter

Tags: shell, automator

I want to create an **Automator Service** for the following conversion(text selection).

*Sorting wrt second parameter*

INPUT:

```
#define Type1 String(@"Type1", @"Other")
#define Type2 String(@"Type2", @"Britain")
#define Type3 String(@"Type3", @"America")
#define Type4 String(@"Type4", @"Canada")
```

OUTPUT:

```
#define Type3 String(@"Type3", @"America")
#define Type2 String(@"Type2", @"Britain")
#define Type4 String(@"Type4", @"Canada")
#define Type1 String(@"Type1", @"Other")
```

I am aware that i can use `sort | uniq` command but that will sort from Left to Right.
But i wanna sort wrt second parameter as shown above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
sort -k 4 your_file
```

where `-k 4` indicates the 4th column is the one to sort on.

OUTPUT:

```
#define Type3 String(@"Type3", @"America")
#define Type2 String(@"Type2", @"Britain")
#define Type4 String(@"Type4", @"Canada")
#define Type1 String(@"Type1", @"Other")
```